# What framework introduced c# version 1.2

Tags: c#

I've got a copy of the Word document "C# Language Specification Version 1.2" and was wondering in which framework this was introduced. I can't remember there is something like .NET Framework 1.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# 1.2 was introduced in .NET v1.1. I have very little idea why, to be honest, and I've never seen a C# 1.1 specification. It's possible that it had something to do with an ECMA spec revision, although that has somewhat separate version numbers anyway.

There weren't many changes in 1.2 compared with 1.0. One important one was that as of v1.2 `foreach` calls `Dispose` on the iterator at the end in a finally block, if the iterator implements `IDisposable`.

See also ["What are the correct version numbers for C#?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c)

Comment: C# 1.1 specs ? Sure. Here you go: http://web.archive.org/web/20061021071655/www.asprelated.com/csharp/sharp-content.aspx.htm. Just kidding. Must be a typo, and it is only visible is a now dead website (hence the archive.org link)

Answer (score 2):

It was in .net 1.1 I've no ideas why the they called it 1.2