# returning from anonymous delegate in C# 3.0

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, delegates

If you are in a method and you pass in an anonymous delegate, does the 'return' key word return a value for the anonymous delegate, or does it return the function?  I know in ruby, they use 'next' to achieve this type of functionality inside of a block.

Here's an example:

```
public bool X()
{
   AList.Where(x => 
    {
       if (x.val == 1) return true;

       ....
       return someBool;
    }
   ...
   return anotherBool
}
```

Comment: Some one with the rights to edit this should change to title.  There is no such thing as C# 3.5.  (See this post if you are confused on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> does the 'return' key word return a value for the anonymous delegate, or does it return the function?

It returns from the anonymous delegate.

.Where() doesn't return a bool, you might try .Any()

```
public bool X()
{
  bool result = AList.Any(x => x.val == 1);
  return result;
}
```

Or you could use a captured variable:

```
bool y = false;
Func<int, bool> checker = x =>
{
  if (x == 1)
  {
     return true;
  }
  y = true;
  return false;
}

AList.Where(checker).ToList();
```