# Linq to EF - Unsupported Functions

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm making a query with Linq, backed by an Entity Framework datasource.

I'm getting the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Sqrt(Double)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here's a simplified version of my function (my version is more complex and uses ACos, sin, cos and other C# Math class functions).

```
  var objects =
            from n in context.Products.Where(p => p.r == r)
            let a = Math.Sqrt((double)n.Latitude)
            where a < 5
            orderby a
            select n;

        return objects.Take(100).ToList();
```

I think the problem may be related to the situation that Linq to EF (and a SQL datasource) has a limited set of supported function compared to Linq to SQL. I'm relatively new to this so I'm not 100% sure.

Can anyone give me a pointer in the right direction?

Cheers,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616235/using-sqrt-in-a-linq-ef-query/4119792#4119792

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try [SquareRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466219.aspx) function defined in `SqlFunctions`

```
    var objects =
        from n in context.Products.Where(p => p.r == r)
        let a = SqlFunctions.SquareRoot((double)n.Latitude)
        where a < 5
        orderby a
        select n;

    return objects.Take(100).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you start of learning LINQ with LINQ-to-objects, you'll run into this a lot once you start using LINQ-to-Entities.

You can do pretty much anything that will compile in LINQ-to-objects, because LINQ-to-objects translates into **code** when compiled.

LINQ-to-Entities (and LINQ-to-SQL) translates into **expression trees**.  So, only the syntax that that specific LINQ provider allowed for is valid.  In my first "for real" LINQ-to-Entities expression, which compiled just fine, I ran into this error about 5 times, as one by one I removed code that wasn't handled by LINQ-to-Entities.

So when you see this, it's normal and common.  You need to find another way each time.

You could avoid the problem with a logical equivalent:

```
var objects =
    from n in context.Products.Where(p => p.r == r)
    where (double)n.Latitude < 25
    orderby a
    select n;

return objects.Take(100).ToList();
```

You could also pull all the data to the client and then run your code using LINQ-to-objects:

```
var objects =
    from n in context.Products.Where(p => p.r == r).ToList()
    let a = Math.Sqrt((double)n.Latitude)
    where a < 5
    orderby a
    select n;

return objects.Take(100).ToList();
```

Finally, you should be able to do this math on the server.  Check out the *System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions* **SqlFunctions Class**.  These functions *will* translate into the expression.  [This in particular looks like it might be the ticket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466292.aspx).

Comment: I used the functions in the SqlFunctions class. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
var objects =
        from n in context.Products.Where(p => p.r == r)
        let a = Math.Pow((double)n.Latitude, 0.5)
        where a < 5
        orderby a
        select n;
```