# Math functions within Linq to Entities

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities

I have some older methods using sql strings and connections that I'm trying to convert to Linq to Entities.

I have rewritten the sql to an ef query as follows;

```
Using ctx As New DataEntities()
        Dim station As String = (From sta In ctx.weather_stations
                                 Let distance = SqlFunctions.SquareRoot(Math.Pow(69.1 * (sta.latitude - lat), 2) + Math.Pow(69.1 * (longi - sta.longitude) * SqlFunctions.Cos(sta.latitude / 57.3), 2))
                                 Where distance < withinRange
                                 Order By distance
                                 Select sta.station_id).Take(1).ToString()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(station) Then
            Return station
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End UsingData
```

This gives an error, 
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Sqrt(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Can this query be done in Linq to EF? If so, how can I reconstruct this query to work?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354716/linq-to-ef-unsupported-functions; you need to use the `SqlFunctions` static helper class.

Comment: That does solve the sqrt problem but im getting this error now on cos,

Comment: The specified method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double] Cos(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' on the type 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression. See my query edit above

Comment: The sta.longitude is NOT a nullable value.

Comment: IT does not have to be. There is implicit conversion between `T` and `Nullable<T>` defined.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek...Then how do I change the query to satisfy this error?

Comment: You changed `Math.Sqrt` into `SqlFunctions.SquareRoot`, but nothing else. I would have expected the exception to disappear. Is there still a problem?