# Returning a Distinct IQueryable with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I'm writing a Function that pulls Records from a DataBase using LINQ to get an IQueryable. This LINQ statement will pull all of the records for Active users within a certain time period, and then spit the UserID, First Name, and Last Name out to a Telerik RadGrid.

My problem lies within trying to get a Distinct Value on the UserID when pulling this Data. I have tried re-working this code to get my result. Here is the an example of the code that is pulling all of the Data, with the Distinct NOT working.

```
public static IQueryable GetActiveEmployees_Grid(string Period)
{
    DataContext Data = new DataContext();
    var Employees = (from c in DataSystem_Records
                     where c.Period == Period
                     orderby c.DataSystem_Employees.LName
                     select c).Distinct();

    return Employees;
}
```

After applying the DataSource to my Grid, this returns the User 4 times, one instance for each Record for that Period.

[image]

Is there a way to apply Distinct to my LINQ Function to make this work the way I intend it to?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simplest way I have found to do this with object is using the groupby then selecting the first.

```
public static IQueryable GetActiveEmployees_Grid(string Period)
{
    DataContext Data = new DataContext();
    var Employees = (from c in DataSystem_Records
                     where c.Period == Period
                     orderby c.DataSystem_Employees.LName
                     select c).GroupBy(g=>g.DataSystem_Employees.AccID).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault());

    return Employees;
}
```

This is not tested but the general concept is there.

**Edit**: I remembered originally finding the answer somewhere on here. Check out this for grouping objects by a certain property.
[LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property/491832#491832)

Comment: The GroupBy worked perfect! I initially tried the GroupBy when Troubleshooting, but I had missed the .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).  Thanks!

Comment: The order by should be in the select after the group by before the firstordefault. assuming you care about the login time.

Answer (score 10):

If you limit the objects you are returning to only the fields that you want to display, it will work properly.

```
public static IQueryable GetActiveEmployees_Grid(string Period)
{
    DataContext Data = new DataContext();
    var Employees = (from c in DataSystem_Records
                     where c.Period == Period
                     orderby c.DataSystem_Employees.LName
                     select c.DataSystem_Employees.FName, 
                            c.DataSystem_Employees.LName, 
                            c.ID).Distinct();

    return Employees;
}
```

Comment: In theory this should have worked, but IntelliSense denied me when trying to add more than one Entity to the Statement.

Comment: @sgriffinusa, you need to `select new {}`... as it is your syntax is invalid

Answer (score 4):

try and write an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for the object type being selected and use it in your `Distinct` method

Comment: this will use linq to objects not a composed query

Answer (score 2):

Making some assumptions around the names of the various fields in the objects:

```
public static IQueryable GetActiveEmployees_Grid(string Period)
{
    DataContext Data = new DataContext();
    var Employees = (from c in DataSystem_Records
                     where c.Period == Period
                     orderby c.DataSystem_Employees.LName
                     select new { FirstName = c.DataSystem_Employees.FName, LastName = c.DataSystem_Employees.LName, ID = c.DataSystem_Employees.ID }).Distinct();

    return Employees;
}
```

To follow the MVC pattern you might want to lift this query into your Model and return a specific class that contains those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Distinct() method to do this.
Eg:

```
var query = from Notification in db.Notifications

                        select Notification.client ;
            query=query.Distinct();
```

The resulting query will only contain distinct values.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are pulling back fields that will make each row distinct.  Like sgriffinusa said, only pull back the 3 values you are displaying.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to implement a custom comparer for Distinct method. Please refer to a previous SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620964/linq-distinct-with-custom-comparer-leaves-duplicates).