# LINQ query to return distinct field values from list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

```
class obj
{
    int typeId; //10 types  0-9 
    string uniqueString; //this is unique
}
```

Assume there is a list with 100 elements of objs, but only 10 unique typeIDs.

Is it possible to write a LINQ query that returns the 10 unique ints from the list of objs?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

```
objList.Select(o=>o.typeId).Distinct()
```

Comment: The second form seems to use an overload of Distinct which doesn't exist as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Oops, removed the second one, thanks @Jon Skeet, that can be done with IEqualityComparer

Comment: As Jon Skeet mentioned, this will only return the properties specified in the Select.

Answer (score 81):

Assuming you want the full object, but only want to deal with distinctness by `typeID`, there's nothing built into LINQ to make this easy. (If you *just* want the `typeID` values, it's easy - project to that with `Select` and then use the normal `Distinct` call.)

In [MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io/) we have the [`DistinctBy`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) operator which you could use:

```
var distinct = list.DistinctBy(x => x.typeID);
```

This only works for LINQ to Objects though.

You can use a grouping or a lookup, it's just somewhat annoying and inefficient:

```
var distinct = list.GroupBy(x => x.typeID, (key, group) => group.First());
```

Comment: To have DistinctBy to appear you need to add the namespace Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities

Comment: @Shil: No, I was writing about the DistinctBy in MoreLINQ. Nothing to do with Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.

Comment: Now I can see there is an overload of Distinct in LINQ which take an IEqualityComparer as parameter and return a list of distinct objects depending upon the implementation of methods in IEqualityComparer

Comment: @DipenduPaul: Yes, but that still means creating an equality comparer for a given property, which is annoying and makes it harder to read. If you can take the MoreLINQ dependency, I think that's cleaner.

Answer (score 57):

If just want to user pure Linq, you can use groupby:

```
List<obj> distinct =
  objs.GroupBy(car => car.typeID).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

If you want a method to be used all across the app, similar to what [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) does:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (!seenKeys.Contains(keySelector(element)))
        {
            seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element));
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this method to find the distinct values using just the Id property, you could use:

```
var query = objs.DistinctBy(p => p.TypeId);
```

you can use multiple properties:

```
var query = objs.DistinctBy(p => new { p.TypeId, p.Name });
```

Comment: Thanks for the _multiple properties_ part!

Comment: .NET 6 now has the distinctBy extension method. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 7):

Sure, use [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx).

Given a collection of `obj` (e.g. `foo`), you'd do something like this:

```
var distinctTypeIDs = foo.Select(x => x.typeID).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what your looking for:

```
    var objs= (from c in List_Objects 
orderby c.TypeID  select c).GroupBy(g=>g.TypeID).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault());
```

Similar to this [Returning a Distinct IQueryable with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472369/returning-a-distinct-iqueryable-with-linq/4472480#4472480)

Comment: `.First` is fine, since you wouldn't have the group if there wasn't something in it.

Comment: You can use an alternative overload of `GroupBy` to make this simpler too - see my answer for an example.

Answer (score 5):

If just want to use Linq, you can override **Equals** and **GetHashCode** methods.

**Product** class:

```
public class Product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Product))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var other = (Product)obj;
        return Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Main** Method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product{ ProductName="Product 1",Id = 1},
            new Product{ ProductName="Product 2",Id = 2},
            new Product{ ProductName="Product 4",Id = 5},
            new Product{ ProductName="Product 3",Id = 3},
            new Product{ ProductName="Product 4",Id = 4},
            new Product{ ProductName="Product 6",Id = 4},
            new Product{ ProductName="Product 6",Id = 4},
        };

        var itemsDistinctByProductName = products.Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var product in itemsDistinctByProductName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Product Id : {product.Id} ProductName : {product.ProductName} ");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: This only makes sense for a class where equality is completely determined by the property you wish to query! I recommend using any other answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to bind a particular data to dropdown and it should be distinct.
I did the following:

```
List<ClassDetails> classDetails;
List<string> classDetailsData = classDetails.Select(dt => dt.Data).Distinct.ToList();
ddlData.DataSource = classDetailsData;
ddlData.Databind();
```

See if it helps