# Get a list of unique strings from duplicate entries

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for a LINQ function that returns a list of unique strings from a list of objects which contain these strings. The strings of the objects are not unique. Like this:

List before:

```
name="abc",value=3
name="xyz",value=5
name="abc",value=9
name="hgf",value=0
```

List this function would return:

```
"abc","xyz","hgf"
```

Does such a function even exist? Of course I know how I could implement this manually, but I was curious if LINQ can do this for me.

Comment: What is the source list? Is it string list, C# object or something else?

Comment: repost? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231360/linq-query-to-return-distinct-field-values-from-a-list-of-objects

Comment: @dotnetom As I wrote, it's a list of objects containing a string property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates in the list using linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606679/remove-duplicates-in-the-list-using-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var foo = list.Select(p => p.name).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method. So basically you will first project the original objects into a collection of strings and then apply the Distinct method:

```
string[] result = source.Select(x => x.name).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(from object in objectList
 select object.name).Distinct();
```