# How to save a complex object in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm writing unit tests for a C# / SQL Server application. MS recommends using SQLite when not using a production db for testing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#inmemory-provider). I have SQLite setup and I'm trying to fill the db with test data. I exported a sample of production data into JSON format and saving that with the test project so I can update the test data fairly easily. The code to setup the SQLite context I took from the MS article.

There's no line numbers to ref but this block

```
var memoryData = new ReqestDataInMemory();
var data = memoryData.AllRepositoryRequests();
```

This gets the json and returns the complex object structure as an `IEnumerable`. I then try and save it to the `DbContext`:

```
public class TestDbContext
{
    public SqliteConnection _connection {get; set;} 
    public DbContextOptions<TaxonomyContext> _contextOptions { get; set;}

    public TestDbContext()
    {
        // Create and open a connection. This creates the SQLite in-memory database, which will persist until the connection is closed
        // at the end of the test (see Dispose below).
        _connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");
        _connection.Open();

        // These options will be used by the context instances in this test suite, including the connection opened above.
        _contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TaxonomyContext>()
            .UseSqlite(_connection)
            .Options;

        // Create the schema and seed some data
        using var context = new TaxonomyContext(_contextOptions);

        if (context.Database.EnsureCreated())
        {
            using var viewCommand = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
            viewCommand.CommandText = @"
                CREATE VIEW AllRequests AS
                SELECT Url
                FROM Request";
            viewCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        var memoryData = new ReqestDataInMemory();
        var data = memoryData.AllRepositoryRequests();

        context.AddRange(data);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The `AddRange()` throws an error

> System.InvalidOperationException : The instance of entity type 'RequestType' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'RequestTypeId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

which makes sense if it's trying to save the lookup table over and over. Hence my problem.

Here is the object I'm working with. `RequestType` is where I'm running into a blocker and its a simple lookup table `RequestType.Id and RequestType.Name`. `Status` is a one-to-many-lookup table. All have FK relationships back to `Request`

The `ChangeDetail` object is details about the request. It has unique IDs and a FK to the Request.

I tried NULLing both `RequestType` and `Statuses` but it s

```
public class Request
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>changed from "navarchar(max)" to "text" for sqlite testing db </summary>
    [Required]
    [MinLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Justification { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required]
    public int SubmitUser { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime SubmitDate { get; set; }
    public int? ModifyUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ChangeDetail> ChangeDetail { get; set; } = new List<ChangeDetail>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<Status> Statuses { get; set; } = new List<Status>();
    public virtual RequestType RequestType { get; set; } = new RequestType();
}
```

My queries work great so I think all my relationships are solid.  Just in case it helps, here are the relationships.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
            .HasOne(x => x.RequestType)
            .WithMany(x => x.Requests);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
            .HasMany(x => x.ChangeDetail)
            .WithOne(x => x.Request);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Statuses)
            .WithMany(x => x.Requests);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Status>()
            .HasOne(x => x.RequestStatusType)
            .WithMany(x => x.Statuses);
}
```

To solve the problem I tried this:
[LINQ query to return distinct field values from list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231360/linq-query-to-return-distinct-field-values-from-list-of-objects)

I thought this showed promise, using Entity.Unmodified but couldn't get it to work
[Save detached entity in Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451461/save-detached-entity-in-entity-framework-6)

This talks about the FK, which I have setup but maybe its not referencing them on save?

[How do I stop Entity Framework from trying to save/insert child objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441027/how-do-i-stop-entity-framework-from-trying-to-save-insert-child-objects)

I appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Comment: Problem in method that you have hidden. `AllRepositoryRequests ` generates duplicate objects `RequestType` which have the same Id.

Comment: yes, that is correct.  In Request Type is repeated because its a lookup in the prod db.  If I try and "seed" the in-memory db with the lookup values, it still tries to save the Request Type object which I'm trying to stop.

Comment: Do not create entity with the same id. Create one and reuse in other references. Or if it is already in database, mark it as `Unchanged` in ChangeTracker. But it still should be one instance.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would close the loop on this.  It took me a while but it was a data issue in one of the joining tables for the many-to-many relationships.  Once I fix