# Not getting Distinct Items when using Linq to List?

Tags: c#, linq

Here is how I am attempting to get a distinct List of items...

```
    var queryResults = PatientList.Distinct();
    PatientList = queryResults.ToList<SelectListItem>();
```

For some reason, I am not getting a distinct list here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinct not working with LINQ to Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365748/distinct-not-working-with-linq-to-objects)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
var queryResults = PatientList.GroupBy(x=>x.Id).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault())
    PatientList = queryResults.ToList<SelectListItem>();
```

You can always try

```
 PatientList = PatientList.GroupBy(x=>x.Id).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList<SelectListItem>();
```

It will give you the distinct results based off whatever you group by

Check out http://blog.jordanterrell.com/post/LINQ-Distinct()-does-not-work-as-expected.aspx

Also another question for reference: [Returning a Distinct IQueryable with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472369/returning-a-distinct-iqueryable-with-linq)

Comment: The type argument for method yadda yadda cannot be inferred from the usage.  Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @DmainEvent, Change x.Id to whatever you need to group everything by. Not sure what you mean by your comment, which argument cannot be inferred?

Comment: sorry about that.  I am working on a different computer right now to right this message than the one that has the code (Little lazy this morning :-) ).  But I did change it to the right value...  Not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: @DainEvent, hmm Ok well which line did you get that error on? The groupby or where your converting to a list? The groupby should work correct what are you grouping everything by? What you are doing is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472369/returning-a-distinct-iqueryable-with-linq

Comment: @Gage...
I was doing my usual and being an idiot.  I forgot to put () at the end of FirstOrDefault.  It works now.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what kind of items your PatientList contains, but I guess you have to implement IEquatable on your custom object.

This have been aswered before here:
[Distinct not working with LINQ to Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365748/distinct-not-working-with-linq-to-objects)

Comment: If you implement it in the objects being compared, that would be IEquatable, not IEqualityComparer...

Comment: It is actually a List of SelectListItem's

Answer (score 1):

Your `SelectListItem` class needs to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` (and optionally implement `IEquatable<SelectListItem>`). Otherwise, different instances with the same values will be considered different.

Another option is to implement a `IEqualityComparer<SelectListItem>` and pass it as the second parameter to `Distinct`.