# With LINQ DISTINCT a Data Table Multiple Columns Excluding a Single Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a C# `DataTable`. I am retrieving Data into `DataTable`. After that I am trying to DISTINCT entry's at the same time creating a `List<MyObject>`.

Here is the code with what I am chasing with:

```
viewModelList = (from item in response.AsEnumerable()
                 select new
                 {
                     description = DataTableOperationHelper.GetStringValue(item, "description"),
                     unitCost = DataTableOperationHelper.GetDecimalValue(item, "unitcost"),
                     defaultChargeable = DataTableOperationHelper.GetBoolValue(item, "defaultChargeable"),
                     contractId = DataTableOperationHelper.GetIntValue(item, "contractID"),
                     consumableid = DataTableOperationHelper.GetIntValue(item, "consumableid")
                 })
                 .Distinct()
                 .Select(x => new ConsumablesViewModel(
                     x.description,
                     x.unitCost,
                     x.defaultChargeable,
                     x.contractId,
                     x.consumableid)
                 )
                 .ToList();
```

I just want to exclude a single column (`consumableid`) when I am doing DISTINCT. How could I DISTINCT with my rest of the Data Excluding a single value (`consumableid`)?

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answered question ([LinQ distinct with custom comparer leaves duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620964/linq-distinct-with-custom-comparer-leaves-duplicates)).

Basically, you create an equality comparer for your type that allows you to decide what makes an object distinct.