# Re: How to displayy checkboxes!

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I need help to figure out how to display checkboxes in a asp:Panel. I need 2 columns and the data is from the database.

Here's the code snippet:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">   
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbProduct" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsProductNames"   
     DataTextField="'<%# Eval("product_name") %>'" 
     RepeatColumns="2" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" CssClass="cbl"> 
</asp:CheckBoxList>         
<%--OnDataBound="cbl_DataBound"--%>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Retag.  There is no C#3.5 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want the checkbox class, created in ASP.net markup using:

```
<asp:CheckBox ...
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.aspx for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DataList control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx). Use **RepeatColumns** property to get 2 columns in a row.