# Does C# 2.0-3.0 have named arguments support for methods?

Tags: c#, syntax, named-parameters

Is there a way to have named arguments like in perl/python

for example

```
object.method(arg1 => value1, arg2 => value2, arg3 => 0);
```

in C# prior to C# 4.0?

Comment: There's a C# 2.5?  Was this supposed to be 3.5?

Comment: .NET 3.5, C# 3.0 ..., it's commonly called "C# 3.5"

Comment: surely, 3.5, not 2.5 - just mistyped

Comment: @C.Ross - Which is a common mistake! The language spec is for C# 3.0 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I'm still living back in the C#2/.Net 2.0 world ...

Comment: @Luke - you missed out C#1.2 too :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c

Answer (score 14):

method named arguments are C# 4.0 feature. (You can't have method optional parameters in C# < 4.0)

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible before C# 4.0.

BTW, there is no such thing as C# 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

While not an exact match for named arguments, there is something in C# 3.0 for constructors that is similar called "[object initializers](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/09/09/c-3-0-features-object-initializers.aspx)" that let you define values for public properties when you use the `new` operator.  This lets you do stuff like this:

```
Person p = new Person()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Address = new Address()
    {
        Street = "1234 St.",
        City = "Phoenix"
    }
};
```

Now in order to utilize this you have invoke the `new` operator (so it won't work for methods) and the properties that you are setting need to have the same access that they would have to allow you to do this:

```
Person p = new Person();

p.FirstName = "John";
p.LastName = "Doe";

Address a = new Address();
a.Street = "1234 St.";
a.City = "Phoenix";

p.Address = a;
```

So this won't let you circumvent `public get` but `protected set` properties (you can't make a property only initialized via this method).  This can make your code more readable, though not to the degree that named arguments can.