# c# version number that comes with .net 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, version

what is the c# version number that comes with .net 2.0? Any suggestion...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the correct version numbers for C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET 2.0 includes C# 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

c# 2. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx for the full story.