# What is C# 5 and where does it come from?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I know C# 3.5 is used with VS2008 and .NET 3.5.
Also C# 4 is part of VS2010 and .Net 4.0 .
But what is C# 5? What IDE?

Comment: There's no such thing as C# 3.5. There's C# 3.0; the C# 3.0 compiler shipped with .NET 3.5.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c

Comment: you might have heard some Jon skeet fact that he already wrote C# 5 :)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

At the recent PDC, Anders announced:

- We plan to release a "C# 5" product and a "VB 11" product. The exact names of the products have not been announced yet to my knowledge
- We intend that the "big ticket" feature of C# 5 and VB 11 will be improved asynchronous programming.
- A prototype version of the "async" feature is available for public download now.
- We plan to at some future date release a "compiler as a service" API for C# and VB. You should not expect that to ship at the same time as C# 5 / VB 11; they are separate products.

Anders specifically did *not* announce:

- When we plan to ship any of these products
- What "ship vehicle" they will go out in; we have not announced a new version of the IDE or the CLR.
- What additional features, if any, will be added to C# 5 or VB 11.

For more information on the async feature in C#, check out the C# dev center or read my [Async articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20150218022347/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/async/) on the subject.

Comment: Do you think you could update this answer please, now that async is part of 4.5? thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's not released yet. Parts of it was presented at this year's [PDC (professional developer conference)](http://microsoftpdc.com/). You can see [Anders Hejlsberg's talk online](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/1b127a7d-300e-4385-af8e-ac747fee677a) where he explains the new async features that will end up in C# 5.0 when it is released (no dates yet)

Answer (score 5):

I heard in an announcement that C# 5 comes from Microsoft in Beijing.

- Asynchronous methods
- Compiler as a service

At the moment I can't find information about .NET 5 or in which IDE it will be released.

More info can be found on the MSDN Forums.

> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/00cc045a-f9e6-402c-bffb-feb4fe1e0611/
>
> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/00cc045a-f9e6-402c-bffb-feb4fe1e0611/

Answer (score 5):

In case people still following this question. It seems the next framework version will be 4.5 and the next VS version will be 11. I am not sure why it is not 2011, probably because it is 2012 now and it is still in technology preview.

What's New for Visual C# in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview. This prerelease will end on June 30, 2012.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156499(v=vs.110).aspx

.NET Framework 4.5 Beta

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/hh854779.aspx

Comment: Its version 11 because it is the 11th version =) Look in your program files directory. 10 is 2010. 9 is 2008. 8 is 2005...

Comment: It's version 11 because it's a law of nature that Microsoft never maintains a consistent version numbering system for more than a few versions in a row. Look at Windows, Office, etc.

Comment: It seems that the second link is broken.