# Why in MSDN do some resources provide versions of documentation for C# and some others for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msdn

Anyone could help my why in MSDN some resources for C# are provided the list of versions (for a specific topic) as C# (1.0, 2.0, etc) and some other are provided as Visual Studio versions (2003, 2005, etc).

I've read a [question and an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c) provided by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c), describes the differences but I think for example, [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) keyword and [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) both are part of C# the language not parts of libraries in .Net.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I'd refine it: why does the documentation equate a version of VS with a C# version? Or, why don't the docs specify the C# version instead of VS version? Yes, VS 2010 supports C# 4.0, but not exclusively. (Yes the CS 4 compiler ticks down into 3.0 compat mode when required). Likely it's down to 'friendliness'.

Comment: @p.campbell : Kindly edit the question if you would like. English is not my first language. Thanks.

Comment: It appears that the entire [C# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx) specifies Visual Studio versions.  Do you have an example in the documentation that specifies C# versions?

Comment: @Robert: I guess that was my point. The docs equate C# versions with VS versions (i.e. tooling). I can't recall ever seeing MSDN docs for C# versions. I guess if it works for them, and it provides a friendlier way to get folks finding the right info, I can't fault MSDN for that.

Comment: @Robert: Actually .Net versions, sorry, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is a C# keyword although other .NET languages may have equivalent keywords e.g. VB.NET has [`ParamArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct363x9h%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

[`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) is a .NET framework interface and not C# specific.

I suspect that a lot of resources on MSDN are auto-generated by some tool, similar to **[SandCastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/)**. I would imagine that this tool outputs markup that includes all of Microsoft's popular modern languages.

Answer (score 1):

`params` is part of the C# language proper.  `IEnumerable` is part of the .NET Framework.

Look at the [downloadable Express versions of Visual Studio,](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CS) and you will see that each version of C# is tightly tied to the version of Visual Studio that supports it, while the `.NET Framework` is treated as if it were an outside library (which, in certain ways, it is.  It is language-agnostic, for example).