# c# 4.0, async CTP and async C# 5.0 are compatible?

Tags: c#, async-await, async-ctp

I have an application that use async CTP library to be able to use async/await keywords, and I know that the actual version of C#, 5.0, has this feature by default, and it is not all the exact version that async CTP. I mean that for example in async CTP exist TaskEx and in C# 5.0 not exists, is Task.

But dispite of these diferences, I would like to know if the Task object that is returned by the async methods are the same or not.

In my case, I have an Interface for a repository to access to the data base. This repository by the moment is implemented by a class that use C# 4.0, but it can use asyc CTP to return a Task and use the await keyowrd. But in the future, I would like to use other classes that use C# 5.0.

If my interace define a method that returns a Task, can I implement this inteface with the class that use C# 4.0 and the class that use C# 5.0? Or exists diference in the Task object in async CTP and C# 5.0?

PD: I correct the version of C#, I mean 5,0 instead of C# 4.5.

PD2: it seems that with VS2012 I can use Microsoft.Bcl.Async and Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack to use the asyn/await keywords in project which target is .NET 4.0. But I don't know which is the difference between them.

Comment: Do you mean [C# 5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c)?

Comment: yes, I mean c# 5.0, and .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same `Task` type that is returned. This type was introduced in .NET 4.0 as part of the Task Parallel Library.

However, I would upgrade everything to VS2012 if I were you, replacing the Async CTP with [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async). The underlying compiler types *are* different (and mutually incompatible), and there are known bugs in the Async CTP as well as installation issues.

Comment: what is the difference between Microsoft.Bcl.Async and Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack? I see that ATP is release before Bcl, but Bcl is beta and ATP is a final version.

Comment: I believe ATP was the first attempt at updating the Async CTP for VS2012. Bcl.Async is a more comprehensive approach (supports more platforms); I expect Bcl.Async to deprecate ATP. However, AFAIK, Microsoft has not stated this.