# Use .NET's own httpClient class on Unity

Tags: c#, web, httpwebrequest, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do a HTTP Delete request from Unity and bump into the idea of use the HttpRequest class included in the System.Web namespace of .Net

How can I achieve this, I supose that some sort of import of that namespace must be done, but how?

Hope some one can give me some orientation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity3D - can I use .NET 4.5 assembly as external library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703689/unity3d-can-i-use-net-4-5-assembly-as-external-library)

Comment: `HttpRequest` is only available in .NET 4.5, but if you did want to do this with the .NET libraries, `HttpWebRequest` has been available since .NET 1.1 and can do what you want. I've not tried to use it from Unity but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HttpClient` is only available in **4.5** NET and above and Unity does not use that version. Unity uses about **3.5** .NET version.

If you are using Unity 5.3, `UnityWebRequest.Delete` can be used to make a Delete request. It can be found in the `Experimental.Networking` namespace. If you are using Unity 5.4 and above,`UnityWebRequest`can be found in the `UnityEngine.Networking;` namespace.

Full working example:

```
IEnumerator makeRequest(string url)
{
    UnityWebRequest delReq = UnityWebRequest.Delete(url);
    yield return delReq.Send();

    if (delReq.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error: " + delReq.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received " + delReq.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

`StartCoroutine(makeRequest("http://www.example.com/whatever"));`

Make sure to include `using UnityEngine.Networking`. You can find complete examples with it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003824/sending-http-requests-in-c-sharp-with-unity/46008025#46008025).

---

**EDIT (UPDATE)**

Unity now supports .NET 4.5 so you can now use HttpClient if you wish. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097965/unity-2017-10f3-net-4-6-target-issue/45098241#45098241) post for how to enable it.

After enabling it, 
Go to `<UnityInstallationDirectory>\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5` or for example, `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5` on my computer.

Once in this directory, copy `System.Net.Http.dll` to your `<ProjectName>\Assets` directory and you should be able to use `HttpClient` after importing the `System.Net.Http` namespace. If there are some other error about missing dependencies, you can get the dlls from this path too and copy them to your `<ProjectName>\Assets` directory too.

Comment: Hi @Programmer your answer its exactly what my approach its aiming at, I was shooting some arrows there but getting to this point, non the less after putting your code to work I'm getting a 401L error code on delReq after sending, an Unauthorized error? whit the WWW class I pass a Dictionary with authorization headers to log in, how do I achieve that here?

Comment: @ASPuma You use `delReq.SetRequestHeader("Your Header", "Your value");`. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: That's all it needs @Programmer some auth, thank you for all your help, my respects!

Comment: I don't suppose you can include an approach that can be used outside the main unity thread?

Comment: @Basic sorry, can you rephrase that comment? I don't understand it.

Comment: I've got a class that doesn't inherit from MonoBehaviour with various things that happen in the background (like maintaining a read-ahead cache to load things from disk). I'd like to extend it to allow it to download content ahead of time too. Since it's not running in the main Unity thread, I can't use any unity engine classes. I seem to be having trouble getting unity to reference any of the Framework classes that would provide me with network connectivity. Is that any clearer? It may justify its own question, but I thought you might know a 1-liner and could expand your (excellent)  answer.

Comment: If you have a class that doesn't doesn't inherit from `MonoBehaviour`, that does not mean that the class is running in another `Thread` unless you explicitly call it's function in another `Thread`. I want to help. If you can create a question and add your code to it, I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Basic Just in case I am not clear you may use any  C# network API in another Thread but can't use Unity API in the answer above in another Thread. If you decide to use C# network API in another Thread, you can use my Thread Wrapper from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330771/use-unity-api-from-another-thread-or-call-a-function-in-the-main-thread/41333540?s=1|41.5690#41333540) answer to simply making calls into main thread from another Thread.

Comment: @Programmer Apologies, I had a holiday and this slipped. I was intentionally running some of my code on a non-UI thread - why impact the frame rate with pre-caching?). I ended up implementing my own callback mechanism to let the ui thread invoke arbitrary callbacks. Thanks for following up though, it's appreciated.

Comment: @Basic *"I had a holiday and this slipped. I was intentionally running some of my code on a non-UI thread"* It's fine to do this. That's how I do my network(TCP/UDP) stuff. *"why impact the frame rate with pre-caching?"* I don't understand this but don't do your network stuff with non Unity API on the main Thread. It's very likely you'll be blocking the main thread.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm aware. I've been writing multi-threaded apps for decades. Apologies if that wasn't clear. I wasn't referring to a threading issue per-se but rather that I didn't want to use Unity's UI thread to do the download, I wanted to do it myself using native.Net classes which I was unable to reference. In any case, it's no longer an issue, so thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, you can use native.Net to do that in another Thread. One disadvantage is that you **can't** build for WebGL platform once you reference any native.Net network stuff or use Thread.  If you don't care about WebGL then go ahead. You are welcome!

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion how to include the System.Net.Http package if I get this error:

`error CS1070: The type `System.Net.Http.HttpContent' has been forwarded to an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral`

Comment: @SimonHeinen what do you need HttpClient  for?

Comment: We are testing unity 2018.2 with .net 4.6 enabled and would like to use a few libraries that are using System.Net.Http. and in general it would be great to migrate away from UnityWebRequest to HttpClient if its fully supported now

Comment: @SimonHeinen I've edited my answer to include how to use `HttpClient` in the latest Unity version. Make sure to remove which ever way you were doing do it this way I mentioned.

Comment: is there any aot/il2cpp build-related issues with system.net.http on old ios/android versions?

Answer (score 5):

In the current versions of Unity httpClient is supported out of the box even on .NET Standard 2.0 targets. Here is sample code on how I use it to access a REST api.

```
public static async Task<Resource> GetResource()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/session");
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return null;
            var resourceJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonUtility.FromJson<Resource>(resourceJson);
        }
    }
```

Copy of my answer on https://forum.unity.com/threads/httpclient-on-net-standard-2-0.608800/