# HttpClient with Unity / Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm currently playing around with Hololens and Hololens-programming. For my task I need to communicate with my REST API and build some stuff with the data.

I'm trying to use the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#sending-a-get-request-to-retrieve-a-resource) for my task.

I installed it with `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`, so it works, when I'm in Visual Studio 2017 for editing the scripts. The Namespace `System.Net.Http` works fine.

But when I switch to Unity, it keeps telling me the following:

> Assets/Scripts/RestClient.cs(77,46): error CS1061: Type
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' does not contain a definition for
>   'ReadAsAsync' and no extension method 'ReadAsAsync' of type
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' could be found. Are you missing an
>   assembly reference?

It references this code snippet from the microsoft documentation I linked before:

```
static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
{
    Product product = null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
    }
    return product;
}
```

It simply says, there is no `ReadAsAsync<T>()`, but it works in Visual Studio 2017 and it's in the docu. I'm so confused right know.

I'm trying to solve this already almost the whole day.

Already did: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097965/unity-2017-10f3-net-4-6-target-issue/45098241#45098241)

Comment: Unity regenerates its solutions, meaning it can (and often does) loose assembly references that have been added via e.g.: NuGet. Did you manually install the downloaded DLL into the assets folder? That should work

Comment: What is the reason you are not using the built in WWW class that comes with unity?

Comment: Unity is mono. When u build for HL it is uwp in vs. Those are two different versions of .net.

Comment: UnholySheep no i just used the command i mentioned.
ScottChamberlain this class got some nice extras.
Everts i kinda don't understand what u mean with that.

Comment: Try the following Unity package https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/rest-client-for-unity-102501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your code with the platform #define directive **NETFX_CORE**. Example:

```
#if !NETFX_CORE
    Debug.LogError("API is restricted to Universal Windows Platform"); // Error in Editor and elsewhere but not on UWP i.e. Hololens
#else
    // your UWP specific code to run on Hololens
#endif
```

Unity platform #define directives : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Also, make sure you have the **InternetClient** capability checked in Player Settings/Publishing Settings/Capabilities to send your messages over Internet. If you intend to work on a local network, you will need the **PrivateNetworkClientServer** capability instead.

Comment: Yes I got a local REST server on my local network running. I can also do requests with my smartphone. When I start my app on Unity, everything works fine. But when i deploy my app to the hololens, which is also in the same network, it doesn't work. I get the errormessage from WWW class while debugging: **Cannot connect to destination host**. I checked all the capability, which had Network or Internet in his name, but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know about WWW class on a local network but with more efforts you could use Unity HLAPI for networking : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingHLAPI.html