# How to upgrade to C# 5?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

This seems like it should be easy, but searching on the web has not turned up anything. I want to take advantage of C#'s async and await, but I have C# version 4.0.30319 (which I got from `Console.Write(typeof(string).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion);`).

I just upgraded from VS12 to VS13, and I am using .NET 4.5. I thought my C# version would upgrade as well, but it hasn't (async and await still give errors).

Any ideas?

Comment: Provide example of one of the code issues as an example.

Comment: @Servy why dont you post this as an answer..I will upvote

Comment: @apomene I'm tempted to, and yet it doesn't explain why his code isn't compiling...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the correct version numbers for C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c)

Comment: He also hasn't posted a code example which might show what the problem is.

Comment: The only thing I can think of at this point is the Language Version is not set to default on the project. Open up your Project's properties, click the "Build", then "Advanced", and see what "Language Version" is set to.

Comment: @StevenJeffries can you post code of async/await code you are attempting to use and what error it is giving?

Comment: @Black Frog: semi-duplicate, the OP is more interested in why some code won't run then in what C# version matches to what framework version.

Comment: @Otis, since the OP hasn't posted any code, this question is a duplicate because the title say how do I upgrade to c# 5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Versioning is complex...

- There's the version of the [.NET runtime, which for you is version 4.5.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx)
- Then there's the version of the C# language being used, which is at least 5.0 if you're using version if you're using VS 2012 or 2013 (You are using C# 5.0 when using C# in those versions of Visual Studio, even if targeting an earlier .NET runtime , which was introduced with version 4.5 of the .NET framework.
- Then there's the Common Language Runtime (CRL), which for you is 4.0.30319, as returned by [Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.imageruntimeversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

What you're checking is not the version of C# - 4.0.30319 is the version of **Common Language Runtime** you are using [(that's what Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion means)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.imageruntimeversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you're using .NET 4.5 on Visual Studio 2013, you're already using C# 5.0.

Comment: Actually, it's the version of the *C# compiler*, not the version of the .NET runtime.  He's using the *compiler* version 4.0.X to compile C# 5.0 code against the .NET 4.5.X runtime.