# When is ASP.NET Core 1.0 (ASP.NET 5 / vNext) scheduled for release?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to decide whether to start my new project on ASP.NET 5 or to stick with the current framework. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a schedule for this project. Github shows that the developers are currently working on its first release candidate. Does Microsoft typically publish expected release dates? If so, where can I find the date they're shooting for?

Comment: Why the down votes and votes to close? This seems like a perfectly legitimate question according to the guidelines.

Comment: Are you talking about a personal project (low risk if it fails) or a professional project (your job depends on it)?

Since Microsoft folks like Scott Hunter have said that we should think of this as a 1.0 release when it comes out, I'd definitely not start a professional project with it yet.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap

Comment: RTM was just released yesterday, 6/27/2016.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

#### Update for July 1, 2016

ASP.NET Core 1.0, Entity Framework 1.0, and .NET Core 1.0 were all released on June 27, 2016.

- [Announcing ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/27/announcing-asp-net-core-1-0/)
- [Announcing Entity Framework Core 1.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/06/27/entity-framework-core-1-0-0-available/)
- [Announcing .NET Core 1.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/06/27/announcing-net-core-1-0/)

---

#### Update for January 19, 2016

- ASP.NET 5 is now called ASP.NET Core 1.0.
- .NET Core 5 is now .NET Core 1.0.
- Entity Framework 7 is now Entity Framework Core 1.0 or EF Core 1.0 colloquially.

For more information see [Scott Hanselman's blog about the change](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx).

---

#### Update for July 2, 2015

In the ASP.NET Community Standup live meeting Damian Edwards discussed some updates to the plans for ASP.NET 5's release. You can read the main points and watch the recording on a [recent team blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/06/30/asp-net-community-standup-june-30-2015.aspx).

This tentative plan was described:

- Beta 6 - end of July 2015
- Beta 7 - end of August 2015
- Beta 8 - end of September 2015
- Release Candidate - late fall 2015 - *Damian warns that this could be completely inaccurate as it is 6 months into the future.*

So, as with all schedules/plans, please take this as a *plan*, not specific dates.

---

#### Original post from December 19, 2014

We (Microsoft) generally don't give specific dates. However, I can say that ASP.NET 5 ("vNext") is being released as part of Visual Studio 2015, and so that means it's being released in 2015 (big surprise!). It is reasonably safe to assume a release in the early half of 2015.

As you correctly noted, the GitHub repos for ASP.NET 5 now specify the RC milestone, which indicates that our main focus right now is on stability, and that the feature set for the RTM release is largely there. There are still features and designs being finalized, and anyone can of course see those going on in the individual repos.

Comment: We have a large site in the works, and we're in the same boat as the OP - trying to decide on using vNext. Can you give us which half (first or second) of 2015 that you suspect it will be released?

Comment: @StephenWatkins - I added a hint that it's most likely the early half of 2015.

Comment: @Eilon Thanks for the update. I'm already starting to move a project which is under development anticipating vnext will be out in the next few months. Is it wise to start using entity framework 7 right away? Or continue with ef6 for now?

Comment: @Yash it will be a while until EF7 has the same level of features as EF6 because it was nearly a complete rewrite. However, if EF7 has the features you need, by all means use it. If there are specific things you're looking for, consider asking a new question here with the [tag:entity-framework-7] tag.

Comment: It will probably be released early May, by the time of Build conference... I hope

Comment: FWIW we are using it in production. There are some frustrations with things swapping around as new betas come out, particularly with Xunit, but that's a tooling issue. It's otherwise been quite stable.

Comment: so is the asp.net vnext released ? and will i be able to create a Vnext project inside visual studio 2012 ?

Comment: @johnG it's not yet released. Support for ASP.NET 5 will be only in VS2015, but also available in many other editors (on many different OSes) via [OmniShar[](http://www.omnisharp.net/).

Comment: Is ASP.NET 5 in VS 2015 RC?

Comment: @Alex Yes, ASP.NET 5 beta 5 is in VS2015 RC (released a couple of weeks ago). Expect some updates from the team about schedule details.

Comment: It is almost end of first half of 2015, it is still not released?

Comment: @hardywang my team is working on the schedule details and we plan to announce it publicly when it is finalized. Please stay tuned!

Comment: It was said on one of 'asp.net community standups' that beta 5 should be in June, beta 6 in July, beta 7 in august and then probably rc in one-two months. Knowing that I would expect rtm or whatever it's called to by by the end of 2015.

Comment: @Eilon Is the schedule details already public? I am just starting a new project for a startup and I don't know if I should go for the new ASP.NET 5 or Node. Knowing when it will be released would be great.

Comment: related question about the "preview" ASP.NET 5 templates, and their completely lame lack of unit-testing at the moment:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730561/how-do-you-unit-test-an-asp-net-mvc-6-controller-or-model-object

Comment: [RC1 seems to be planned for Nov 2015](http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/07/ASP.NET-Roadmap). From the link: `The roadmap for ASP.NET 5 includes three more betas between now and November’s release candidate. And that’s after dropping several important items from the planned release.`

Answer (score 18):

According to Roadmap on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap):

## ASP.NET Core 1.0 (Previously called ASP.NET 5) Schedule and Roadmap

---

Below is the schedule and roadmap for ASP.NET Core 1.0. Please note that these dates and feature plans are all subject to change. As with any project of this size it is difficult to predict exactly when things will land. Even so, we think it's important to be as open and transparent as possible about our plans so that our users can have the right expectations and create their plans accordingly.

### Schedule

---

<kbd>Milestone</kbd>                     <kbd>Release Date</kbd>
<kbd>Beta6</kbd>                           <kbd>27 Jul 2015</kbd>    
<kbd>Beta7</kbd>                           <kbd>24 Aug 2015</kbd>   
<kbd>Beta8</kbd>                           <kbd>21 Sep 2015</kbd>   
<kbd>RC1</kbd>                             <kbd>Nov 2015</kbd>        
<kbd>RC2 (Tools Preview 1)</kbd> <kbd>[mid-May 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/06/net-core-rc2-improvements-schedule-and-roadmap/)</kbd>
<kbd>1.0.0</kbd>                            <kbd>[late-June 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/06/net-core-rc2-improvements-schedule-and-roadmap/)</kbd>

The November release candidate (RC1) will be a supported and production ready cross-platform release. Depending on feedback from RC1 we will ship additional release candidates as necessary.

### Milestone Themes

---

#### Beta6 - Localization, Servicing, .NET 4.6 support, and more

In Beta6 we are working on supporting localization in the new request pipeline. We are also working to enable patching and servicing of the runtime including adding support for strong-naming assemblies. In Beta6 you will be able to target .NET 4.6 using the .NET Execution Environment (DNX). We will do work on response buffering and caching (via HTTP.SYS on Windows) and add distributed caching support via SQL Server.

Planned features:  [Runtime](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A1.0.0-beta6), [MVC](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A6.0.0-beta6), [Razor](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A4.0.0-beta6), [Identity](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A3.0.0-beta6)

#### Beta7 - Cross-platform

The primary focus for Beta7 will be to enable cross-platform development on .NET Core. This includes shipping the .NET Core based .NET Execution Environments for Mac and Linux, enabling the basic developer workflows and also setting up the acquisition story.

Planned features: [Runtime](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A1.0.0-beta7), [MVC](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A6.0.0-beta7), [Razor](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A4.0.0-beta7), [Identity](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A3.0.0-beta7)

#### Beta8 - Feature complete!

Beta8 is the last major feature milestone planned before moving into a stabilization phase for RC1. We will work on enabling complete end-to-end experiences in Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code. We expect cross-platform .NET Core to be feature complete at this point.

Planned features: [Runtime](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A1.0.0-beta8), [MVC](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A6.0.0-beta8), [Razor](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A4.0.0-beta8), [Identity](https://github.com/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Aaspnet+is%3Aissue+label%3Aenhancement+milestone%3A3.0.0-beta8)

#### RC1 - Stabilization

The focus for RC1 will be on polishing existing features, responding to customer feedback and improving performance and reliability. The goal is for RC1 to be a stable and production ready release.

#### RC2 - Move to .NET Core CLI and .NET Platform Standard

For RC2 we will move ASP.NET Core 1.0 to be based on the new  [cross-platform .NET Core command line toolchain](https://github.com/dotnet/cli).

#### Future Work

---

The following features unfortunately won't make it into the initial RTM release. We are tentatively planning on shipping them in the initial feature release after RTM, during Q3<sup>*</sup> of 2016:

- Visual Basic support
- SignalR 3
- Web Pages 4

*<sup>*</sup> References to yearly quarters (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) are calendar-based*

Answer (score 11):

**Update 3**: The ASP.NET Core 1.0 (Previously called ASP.NET 5) roadmap is on github: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap

**Original**

Visual Studio 2015 will released on 20 July 2015.

However according to Somasegar's blog on 29 Jun 2015: "ASP.NET 5 and EF 7 will be released separately at a later date."

Answer (score 11):

**Updated Answer:**

ASP.NET Core 1.0 was released on  June 27 2016.

Getting started with .NET Core

- If you use Visual Studio 2015 ([Visual Studio Community](http://www.visualstudio.com/free) is free!) you should get VS2015 Update 3 first then install the [.NET Core Tools](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817245) for Visual Studio.
- If you don't want to use VS, consider using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for free and install the C# extension from the marketplace along with the [.NET Core SDK for Windows](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=809122). Of course, if you're on Mac/Linux/Whatever, go over to http://dot.net.
- If you want all the advanced and specific downloads for .NET or .NET Core, click [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#core)

**Previous Answer: (Release Candidates)**

Scott Hunter has [blogged specific time-frames:](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/06/net-core-rc2-improvements-schedule-and-roadmap/) for the release of `ASP.NET Core`

> The Core Schedule
>
> .NET Core and **ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2** runtime and libraries will be available in **mid-May**.
>
> Tooling will be Preview 1 and bundled with this release.
>
> .NET Core and ASP.NET **Core 1.0 RTM** (release) runtime and libraries will be available by the **end of June**.
>
> Tooling will be Preview 2 and bundled with this release.
>
> We will continue to make changes and stabilize the tooling until it RTMs with Visual Studio “15”.

**Previous Answer:**

ASP.NET Core 1.0  (previously called ASP.NET 5) [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) is on github but the dates in this roadmap have been missed over the past couple of months  by a  margin so one can't really trust it. Considering this, it makes sense  they have removed fixed dates from the roadmap.

According to the current roadmap RC2 release is TBD. Release 1.0 says 2016.

So the question should really be? When is TBD? When is later in 2016?

Luckily the number of open issues per release can be viewed on github.

Take note: ASP.NET Core release versions needs to integrate with other related /dependent teams releases e.g. Entity Framework team. Each release will only be released once those teams have the equivalent release version ready.

I post links to each of these technologies milestones in github. This should give the most accurate indication of a release date.

[aspnet/Mvc](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/milestones) (RC2 is 99% as on 19 April)
[image]
[aspnet/EntityFramework](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/milestones) (RC2 is 98% as on 19 April)
[image]
[dotnet/cli](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/milestones) (RC2 is 88 % as on 19 April)
[image]
[dotnet/coreclr](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/milestones) (RC2 is 99 % as on 19 April)
[image]
[dotnet/corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/milestones) (RC2 is 100% as on 19 April)

[image]

Based off the above progress, RC2 due date is listed as 29 April  2016 when they will have a build ready for testing

It will probably be another X weeks of testing but at least it's an indication when it will be ready.

Progress is updated daily.

Release 1.0 RTM progress can also be viewed on these links.

RTM milestone date seems to be 30 June although not all of the links have milestone dates. Based on how the RC2 dates have slipped, this date will probably change as well as they progress.

The [ASP.NET Community Standup videos](https://live.asp.net/) should also give a good indication on progress of releases where one can get updates from the horse's mouth, usually on a weekly basis.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any confirmed release dates but if [these new ASP.NET 5 features](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/aspnet-5-overview) or being on the latest framework is important you can always [download the Visual Studio 2015 preview](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs) and start using some of the new features today.

Comment: Thanks, we're already exploring the preview. Knowing if their project dates somewhat align with ours would make our decision much easier.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET 5 was RELEASE CANDIDATE as 11/18/2015. Which means from that point forward using those bits you can use it in production and receive support.