# C# Lifecycle Support

Tags: c#, lifecycle

I want to understand how does the life-cycle of c# works ? Is it tied to the supported operating system ? For e.g C# 5.0 has Windows 2000, Windows 7, Windows 98, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows XP as supported OS. And looking into MS' life-cycle support it looks ALL of them have already reach the end-of-file. So, is fair to say then that C# 5.0 is also coming to EOL ?

Comment: I don't think C# was even a thing on Windows 98 or 2000... See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c/247623#247623)

Comment: Try googling ".net framework support lifecycle"

Comment: I think you're confusing three different things: Windows operating system versions, C# versions, and .NET versions.  Some newer versions of .NET will not work on some older versions of Windows.  C# is a programming language used to build .NET applications - it does not have a "life-cycle."

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek (but true) response: For me, writing in C# 5.0 would be like going back to a prior life. So, yes, C# 5.0 has already reached end-of-life. But, there is no reason, the C# 6.0 compiler can target the same .NET 4 CLR as the C# 5.0 compiler.

Comment: @Scott [Yes, it was supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973853.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft C# compiler is part of the .NET Framework, and the life cycle of the .NET Framework is, as you correctly assume, tied to the operating systems that it is part of.

Details can be found here:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17455/lifecycle-faq-net-framework

The Microsoft C# 5.0 compiler is part of the .NET Framework 4.5. Since the support for .NET 4.5 and 4.5.1 ended on Jan. 12, 2016, an upgrade to .NET 4.5.2 is required to continue receiving technical support.

However, since newer versions of the C# compiler can target earlier versions of the .NET framework, the question is moot - there is simply no convincing reason to use the MS C# 5.0 compiler instead of, for example, the current version of [the .NET compiler platform (Roslyn)](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @BJMyers: I would argue that the Microsoft C# compiler is part of the .NET framework (at least in the pre-Roslyn era).

Comment: I don't see how you can make that argument.  You don't get the C# compiler when you install .NET.  The C# compiler is a standalone component that is used to *build* applications that run on .NET.

Comment: *"You don't get the C# compiler when you install .NET."* I disagree. `csc.exe` *is* contained in the .NET Framework 4.5. I challenge you to find a stand-alone download of the Microsoft C# 5.0 compiler without the .NET Framework.

Comment: Hrm... I stand corrected.  Based on that knowledge, and the edits you've made to differentiate between C# 5.0 and the C# 5.0 compiler, I withdraw my previous complaint.