# SelectedIndexChanged event of ComboBox - populate control values

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

When ComboBox `SelectedIndexChanged` event occurs, I need to populate the respective controls with its values. I am using entity framework 6 for the approach. I am using c# windows forms and .net framework 4.5. My code is :

```
private void comboBoxCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ReliableTradersEntities entities = new ReliableTradersEntities())
    {
        m_blouse = new BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT();
        m_pardi = new PARDI_MEASUREMENT();
        m_lengha = new LHENGA_MEASUREMENT();

        var res = from c in entities.CUSTOMERs
                        join p in entities.PARDI_MEASUREMENT on c.CUSTOMERID equals p.CUSTOMERID
                        join l in entities.LHENGA_MEASUREMENT on c.CUSTOMERID equals l.CUSTOMERID
                        join b in entities.BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT on c.CUSTOMERID equals b.CUSTOMERID
                        select new 
                        {

                            p.PARDILENGTH,
                            p.PARDILIMIT,
                            p.SHOULDER,
                            p.SHOULDERTOHEAD,
                            p.HEADTOBACK,
                            p.HALFHEADROUND,
                            p.NIQABLENGTH,
                            p.KAS,
                            l.LHENGALENGTH,
                            l.LHENGALIMIT,
                            l.BELTOPTION,
                            l.ISPOCKET,
                            l.ISZIP,
                            l.STYLE,
                            l.STYLESIZE,
                            l.ALINE,
                            b.BLOUSELENGTH,
                            b.CHEST,
                            b.WAIST,
                            b.SLEEVES,
                            b.NECK,
                            b.POINT,
                            b.BLOUSEOPENING
                        };
        textBoxPL.Text = m_pardi.PARDILENGTH;
    }

}
```

Comment: Side note: Do **not** use "all uper-case" variable names, it kills the readability. Also, FYI, [.NET 4.5 uses **C# 5.0**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247623/4934172), not **C# 4.0**.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see a question here. What happens when you runs this code? What is the problem?

Comment: @Steve the problem is when I set the m_pardi.PARDILENGTH to the textbox, it is null. so as the other properties. because m_pardi object is null.

Comment: @Steve I need to know how do I initialize the object m_pardi so that I can populate the controls from the object.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, FYI, I did not mentioned that I am using c# 4.0 or 5.0. I just mentioned the framework. but thank you for the knowledge.

Comment: @AbidAli You were using the `[c#-4.0]` tag, I already took care of it, so It's all good :)

Comment: OOPS! that's bad! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created an anonymous type that is returned in the variable *res* with all the info extracted by your query. You have not filled the initial three class instances.

You need to initialize your instances using the *res* variable with

```
// The query returns an IEnumerable, you need to extract the first element
var x = res.FirstOrDefault();
if(x != null)
{
    m_pardi = new PARDI_MEASUREMENT();
    m_pardi.PARDILENGTH = x.PARDILENGTH;
    .... 
}
```

But you could use directly the *res* variable

```
 var x = res.FirstOrDefault();
 if(x != null)
 {
     textBoxPL.Text = x.PARDILENGTH;
     .... and so on....
 }
```

Comment: I don't get res.PARDILENGTH in my intellisence.

Comment: Right, too fast. The return from your query is an IEnumerable, you need to get the first element from that query even if it returns a single record.