# Which version of the C# compiler introduced nullable types?

Tags: c#, nullable

My C# code is being run in a older version of C# (4.0.30319.34209) than in my own development environment. I am wondering if my usage of nullable types will work on this older version of C#. Does anyone know what version of C# nullable types were introduced in? My "Google-fu" came up with nothing.

Comment: `C# 2.0` i believe.

Comment: This is not the C# (language) version you provided.

Comment: Dont you compile your code against the version you need to target?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/247623/4187549

Comment: C# 2.0: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-nullable-types

Comment: side note: you need to be *very* clear in your nomenclature - the C# version and the .NET version *are not strongly linked* - the title asks about the .NET version, but the body asks about the language version; these *need not be related*

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. The 4.0.30319.34209 refers to the compiler version.

Comment: I am looking to see what version of the C# compiler my code needs to target to support nullable types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nullable types are §19.5 in the [C# 2.0 specification](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/8/f/98fdf0c7-2bbd-40d3-9fd1-5a4159fa8044/CSharp%202.0%20Specification_Sept_2005.doc), so: .NET 2.0 and C# 2.0 (it can't have been earlier, as it depends on "generics", which is definitely 2.0)

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable#applies-to), `Nullable` appllies to:

```
.NET Core
2.2 2.1 2.0 1.1 1.0

.NET Framework
4.8 4.7.2 4.7.1 4.7 4.6.2 4.6.1 4.6 4.5.2 4.5.1 4.5 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.0

.NET Standard
2.0 1.6 1.5 1.4 1.3 1.2 1.1 1.0

Xamarin.Android
7.1

Xamarin.iOS
10.8

Xamarin.Mac
3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

C# 2.0 introduced nullable types that allow you to assign null to value type variables. You can declare nullable types using Nullable where T is a type.

Copied from here: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-nullable-types

Answer (score 0):

Here is a history of C# versions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history
It states that nullable types were introduced in C# v2.0. Hope it helps.