# How to do a regex split on multiple words (not characters)

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to do a regex split on multiple words, not just characters

For example the string:

> and(animal = fish)or(food = meat)

Should give me:

```
1: (animal = fish)
2: (food = meat)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Split("and(animal = fish)or(food = meat)", @"and|or")
```

Gives you:

```
[0]: ""
[1]: "(animal = fish)"
[2]: "(food = meat)"
```

If you want to retain the delimiters use:

```
Regex.Split("and(animal = fish)or(food = meat)", @"(and)|(or)")
```

Gives you:

```
[0]: ""
[1]: "and"
[2]: "(animal = fish)"
[3]: "or"
[4]: "(food = meat)"
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly if one of the desired strings contains one of the split word, for example `"and(animal = horse)or(food = meat)"`

Comment: @Lars did you just answer your own question immediately after asking it?

Comment: @ChrisSandvik, https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, But here I see no gain.

Comment: @DragandDrop interesting, I did not know that this was encouraged

Comment: @ChrisSandvik, Many great Self Answer out there : like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c). note that the first one has 38k upvotes.

Comment: Generally, when I'm trying to find an answer on stackoverflow and I can't find it, but I eventually figure it out on my own, I try to add a "self-answer" so it's there for the next person