# How to list supported C# language versions in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, version, csproj

Currently I'm working on a .NET Core 3.1 project where I want to try out some new C#10 features. I get the [CS1617](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1617) error which tells me I cannot do this and offers me to list available languages for this project by using `<langversion>?</langversion>` in .csproj.

My question is where the list of compatible languages shows up.

Comment: You can check list here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: That I've seen, but I'm interested in how to list the compatible language versions - as described on the documentation page...

Comment: Maybe this table will give answers to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38506668/11642651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've inquired at the `dotnet/docs` [repo](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/27101), and the answer can be found there.
It seems that creating this list of compatible language versions is a bit more tricky than it seemed. I'll stick with the list as *Auditive* suggested.