# What version of C# is supported by the relevant flowgear nodes?

Tags: c#, flowgear

I have done all the searching I can think of, and I don't see anything stating which version of C# is available for Script, Expression, or other nodes where C# syntax is used.

So I keep trying to use things like string interpolation or declaring out values inline as arguments, and they work fine where I first try them, in VS, but of course the nodes error-out once I copy-paste and try to run them in flowgear proper.

If someone in-the-know could answer here, that would work almost as well as if the actual [Flowgear Help Center](https://help.flowgear.net/) had that information.

Comment: Have you contacted their support team?

Comment: They have a handy mechanism for contacting support - a direct message widget.  When you go to use it, a message appears saying "Have a technical question? Help us build the community by posting it to Stack Overflow (use the 'flowgear' tag)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this question was asked, Flowgear has updated the help articles ([Script](https://help.flowgear.net/en/articles/1096160-script), [Expression](https://help.flowgear.net/en/articles/1140110-expression)) to list the version of .NET Framework in use. As the current* node version uses .NET Framework  v4.5.1, the [associated version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c) the node compiles to is C# 5.0.

*As Flowgear update their nodes, this information is subject to change, so as mentioned in the question, the help articles are a good first place to look.

Comment: With this information, in visual studio I'm able to isolate node-script code into a separate project "FlowGearThings", edit its project file and add `<LangVersion>5</LangVersion>`  to a PropertyGroup.  This helps prevent me from writing anything that causes unexpected errors once I copy it to the real Script node.