# What C# compiler am I running and what is the latest version of C# syntax it supports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax, compilation, visual-studio-2022

I am overhauling a legacy solution that contains several projects, in their csproj files some have `<LangVersion>default</LangVersion>` and others have a version specified such as  `<LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>`

Now, I have recently discovered that `<LangVersion>default</LangVersion>` basically instructs that the latest major version of C# syntax that is available to the compiler can be utilised.

The usual search around is not unveiling this information.

P.S. I am utilising Visual Studio 2022 Pro and .Net 4.7.2 with .Net 4.81 installed and available on the dev machine, developing a web application, i.e. asp.net, with a variety of class libraries.

**Edit 1**: Worth noting that when setting the language version to 11 in the .props file in the solution folder and using #error version, in the tab that lists errors it says Language version 7.3 but in the 'Output' tab it correctly reports Language version 11.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Thanks but no, that is a good resource for standard information, but when you are working on a legacy project with multiple language version overrides the #error version does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type into your C# file:

```
#error version
```

and it will **tell you**; for example, I see

> Error CS8304  Compiler version: '4.8.0-3.23504.4 (81d92746)'.
>
> Language version: preview.

(the top number is the actual compiler version; the bottom number is after applying `<LangVersion>` etc)

In general: avoid using `<LangVersion>default</LangVersion>` etc because it is ambiguous and depends on the build tools being used; a specific `<LangVersion>10</LangVersion>` is preferable (often in a `Directory.Build.props` file so it doesn't need to be duplicated), as it will give suitable clear messages when not available. This can be combined with `global.json` to ensure suitable build tool versions.

Comment: Perfect thank you `error CS8304: Compiler version: '4.6.0-3.23329.3 (5db00029)'. Language version: 7.3.` and yes I agree about specifying the version, also it does seem a pretty strange decision to have '<LangVersion>latestMajor</LangVersion>' act the same as '<LangVersion>default</LangVersion>'. Please, see my edit.

Comment: Worth noting that when setting the language version to 11 in the .props file in the solution folder and using #error version, in the tab that lists errors it says Language version 7.3 but in the Output tab it correctly reports Language version 11.